# ActionScript 3 flashpunk loading multiple assets through a folder once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, load, assets

I have a folder in my project containing my levels , what I want to achieve is that it loads all xml files in that folder , the only way I know in flash is by embedding each asset which is a pain in a case where I want about 30 levels .

I came from C#/XNA where loading assets using the content.Load was very easy because I had the ability to use it in a for loop , while here in Actionscript 3 I dont know how .

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be downloaded externally without any problem. If on a server a server side script can give your app all the asset names and paths. If on a desktop or mobile your app can find out itself by using the File class.

An example of the File class could be:

```
var directory:File = new File("path to directory");
var allDirectoryFiles:Array = directory.getDirectoryListing();//all file in folder as File instances
for(var i:int = 0; i < allDirectoryFiles.length; i++)
{
    var file:File = allDirectoryFiles[i] as File;
    //get the path or do whatever.
}
```

Comment: Can you give examples of the File class please ?